# how to put custom image in table view cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

In my app i have to implement checkbox functionality in tableview cell.By clicking on that checkbox another label will be created in the same cell.1st how to implement checkbox functionality?i have created custom cell. here is my code which i tried but it doesnt work.

```
   -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

      UIButton *btnUncheck=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(260, 35, 20, 20)];

   btnUncheck=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     btnUncheck.tag=indexPath.row;
// [btnUncheck setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NO.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnUncheck addTarget:self action:@selector(checkBoxClicked:)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[view addSubview:btnUncheck]



    -(void)checkBoxClicked:(id)sender{


     if(favoriteChecked==NO)
 {


    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YES.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     favoriteChecked=YES;
        }
else
{


    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NO.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    favoriteChecked=NO;
        }





}
```

Comment: Please put the code in proper sequence as I am not able to understand what you have put under `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method and where it finishes.Please post the full code. This is not helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast your sender from id type to button type using `UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;` and then change image for `btn`.

Also change `[view addSubview:btnUncheck]` to `[cell.contentView addSubview:btnUncheck];` And for doing that you will require to create a TableViewcell

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

in the block

```
if(cell==nil)
{
     //add the code here
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
try this
if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(3,8,30, 30);
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chack box1_selected_callback.png"] forState:0]
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:button];
    }
```